# Multiple Object creation in Cocos3d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am creating here 3 objects using a for loop .But touch event is only available to one object.Please find a solution for this ...

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    nodef = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile:@"cocos3dMascot.pod"];
    nodef.location = cc3v(0.3,- 3.5f+i*1.5, 0.0f);
    nodef.scale=cc3v(0.2, 0.2, 0);
    nodef.isTouchEnabled=YES;
   // nodef.tag=i;
    [self addChild:nodef];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also put this line `self.touchEnabled = YES;`  in your `init` method for enable touch not only for **nodef**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set to swallow touches on your 3 objects.

replace `nodef.isTouchEnabled=YES` with:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:nodef priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES]
```